# image resizing on post content without css and html tags

Tags: images, optimization, post-content

**Background:**
I am using `WordPress` posts for `Newsletter`. I am importing the posts through an `api` and use them in a `Newsletter` tool to send them out. I am downsizing the featured image before feeding to the Newsletter tool. But now I am facing some troubles, sometimes I have High resolution post content images.

**Issue:**
I need to resize those inner images of post content but without using any `css` and `html` `image tags attributes` as I am using them for the Newsletter purpose.

I know that how to handle that with `html` and `css` tags like bellow;

```
<img class="wp-image-290893 aligncenter lazyloaded" src="https://fcam.b-cdn.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/Finnair_A350_Business_Class_Seat_Champagne_Glass.jpg" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 1000px) 100vw, 1000px" srcset="https://fcam.b-cdn.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/Finnair_A350_Business_Class_Seat_Champagne_Glass.jpg 1985w, https://fcam.b-cdn.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/Finnair_A350_Business_Class_Seat_Champagne_Glass-158x100.jpg 158w, https://fcam.b-cdn.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/Finnair_A350_Business_Class_Seat_Champagne_Glass-768x485.jpg 768w, https://fcam.b-cdn.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/Finnair_A350_Business_Class_Seat_Champagne_Glass-1024x646.jpg 1024w, https://fcam.b-cdn.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/Finnair_A350_Business_Class_Seat_Champagne_Glass-237x150.jpg 237w" data-ll-status="loaded" width="1000" height="631">
```

My question is whether there is anyway to downsize these images if those are exceeding certain width(perhaps 800px) in real. This optimization helps to save lot of bandwidth as per my calculation.

Any help would be really appreciating.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the following: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

eg add this to your theme's functions.php or plugin:

```
add_image_size( 'newsletter-image', 800, 600 ); // 800 pixels wide by 600 pixels tall, soft proportional crop mode
```

Then use the image like this:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
    the_post_thumbnail( 'newsletter-image' ); 
}
```

Comment: How to apply this for `get_the_content()` ? I need to apply image conversion on top of `get_the_content()` and it should return the html text.

Comment: For that you can go to: Dashboard->Settings->Media and set the Max size in there.